# Timing child view layout with UICollectionView layout changes

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, layoutsubviews

I have a UICollectionView that has a custom layout that changes the sizes of its cells when the device rotates.  When the layout changes the size of a cell, layoutSubviews is called on each cell.  This is what I want.  However layoutSubviews does not execute in an animated manner but the change in size of the cell does.  I would like to synchronize the two changes.

For example right now if the cell gets larger, the subviews resize instantly and then the cell size animates its change.  I don't think I should put animation code in layoutSubviews.  Is that correct?  What is the best way to handle this?